# accumulate equal ranges without raw loops

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

In one of the projects I am working on, I have this problem all over the place: I have data that has to be grouped by some sort criterion and the groups have to be accumulated.

Sounds simple:

1. Sort the input range (`std::sort`)
2. Identify the equivalent entries (`std::equal_range`)
3. Accumulate each equal range (`std::accumulate`)
4. Store the accumulation results in some output range

Here is what I came up with:

```
// accumulate equal ranges
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

template <typename ForwardIt,
          typename Compare,
          typename OutputIt,
          typename T,
          typename Sum>
auto accumulate_equal_ranges(ForwardIt first,
                             ForwardIt last,
                             Compare compare,
                             OutputIt dest_first,
                             T initial,
                             Sum sum) -> void
{
  assert(is_sorted(first, last, compare));

  auto equalRange = std::make_pair(first, last);

  for (; first != last; first = equalRange.second)
  {
    equalRange = std::equal_range(first, last, *first, compare);
    *dest_first =
        std::accumulate(equalRange.first, equalRange.second, initial, sum);
  }
}
```

Here is a mini test case:

```
// Test code

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
  using IP = std::pair<int, int>;
  auto values = std::vector<IP>{{0, 1},
                                {0, 2},
                                {0, 3},
                                {0, 4},
                                {1, 0},
                                {1, 0},
                                {1, 0},
                                {1, 0},
                                {2, 4},
                                {2, 3},
                                {2, 2},
                                {2, 1},
                                {3, 7},
                                {3, 7},
                                {3, 7},
                                {3, 7},
                                {4, 23},
                                {5, 42}};

  auto result = std::vector<IP>{};
  accumulate_equal_ranges(begin(values),
                          end(values),
                          [](const IP& l, const IP& r)  // less
                          {
                            return l.first < r.first;
                          },
                          back_inserter(result),  // back_inserter
                          IP{0, 0},
                          [](const IP& l, const IP& r)  // plus<pair>
                          {
                            return std::make_pair(r.first, l.second + r.second);
                          });

  assert((result == std::vector<IP>{
                        {0, 10}, {1, 0}, {2, 10}, {3, 28}, {4, 23}, {5, 42}}));
}
```

Is there a nice way to get rid of the for-loop in the code above using modern C++ features?

Comment: You should put your mini test case here. We like things on our site where they won't die in the future. :)

Comment: That for-loop is why you wrote this function to begin with. So it's not clear why it's important to get rid of it. You're writing an algorithm function; for-loops are allowed.

Comment: are you familiar with std::for_each ?

Comment: `assert` is not for error handling.

Comment: @erip Added test code. Thanks for the hint

Comment: @nicol-bolas Sure, the code using this function will not have a raw loop. Still, for educational reasons, I'd be interested in an implementation of the function without the raw loop.

Comment: @Zohar81 How would `std::for_each` help here?

Comment: Your algorithm seems to be O(n log n), it isn't clear what you are winning here,

Comment: @n.m. The function makes my code shorter and easier to reason about since this is used in several places (that's what I am winning here). The question is about the implementation: Can I get rid of the for-loop?

Comment: I'm talking about efficiency of your implementation. You are using `std::equal_range` which is O(log n). This is suboptimal. A linear search (`find_if` perhaps) looks more efficient here. (No, I don't think you can get rid of the outer loop. Not easily at any rate.)

Comment: @n.m. Hmm. `find_if` is O(m), m being the number of equivalent elements. In the worst case, `m==n`. Thus in the worst case, binary search is probably better. In my use cases n is 100k+ and m is in `[1, 50k]`. I expect several 10k equal ranges. Since the constant factor is probably considerably smaller for `find_if`, You're probably right: `find_if` is more efficient. I will have to measure, though. Thanks for the hint and your answer!

Comment: If your equal ranges are long, your method can actually be more efficient. You should measure on your typical data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way to remove the raw loop using the same approach to the algorithm.  The main issue is that there aren't any standard algorithms that let you jump to different locations in the input range instead of stepping through each one consecutively.  Doing a `std::generate` would almost be what you want if there was a way to specify a separate predicate for when to stop instead of using a fixed end position.

However, if you take a different approach, you can use a `std::for_each()`:

```
template <typename ForwardIt,
          typename Compare,
          typename OutputIt,
          typename T,
          typename Sum>
auto accumulate_equal_ranges_new(ForwardIt first,
                             ForwardIt last,
                             Compare compare,
                             OutputIt dest_first,
                             T initial,
                             Sum sum) -> void
{
  if (last==first) return;

  auto iter = first;
  auto prev = *iter++;
  auto range_sum = sum(initial,prev);

  std::for_each(
    iter,
    last,
    [&](const auto &current){
      if (compare(prev,current)) {
        *dest_first++ = range_sum;
        range_sum = initial;
      }
      range_sum = sum(range_sum,current);
      prev = current;
    }
  );

  *dest_first++ = range_sum;
}
```

This does have the advantage that it has a better worst-case complexity (O(n) instead of O(n*log(n))), but it would only require a small change to your algorithm to fix that (using `std::adjacent_find` instead of `std::equal_range`).  Another advantage is that it could work with input iterators instead of forward iterators.

Comment: Nice! Walking through the data linearly is probably better. Btw, you could get rid of `iter`, initialize `range_sum` with `initial` and let the `for_each` run from `first` to `last`.

Answer (score 0):

'No naked for' is only for your main context.

Ie:

```
// bad
void foo() {
    setup();
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
         do_something(i);
    }
    teardown();
}

// better
void bar() {
    setup();
    do_somethings();
    teardown();
}
```

`do_somethings` has the loop in it - naked fors aren't banned - you just shouldn't seem them in you main context. Think in algorithms and not loops.